# Laravel dispatch job run async

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs, laravel-queue

I have a function that posts some content and pushes a job onto a queue and returns response to user even before the queue complete the job.

for that I changed the .env QUEUE_DRIVER to database, And records is saved in table jobs, but to execute this jobs I have to call the command `php artisan queue:work`, and that is my question: how do I call this command in the code or what should I do whenever there is jobs in the table?

Answer (score 0):

The command

> php artisan:queue work

Should be runnig always it will check if there is new jobs he will dispatch them 
But it should be always running you can't execute it from the code 
Also you can run

> php artisan queue:work --tries=5

This for example will try 5 times then it will stop

Plus you can install supervisor it will always start the queue:work if it faild

Comment: I'm using shared hosting, I tried to install supervisor but no luck, any help please.